# How con i resize a label to a smaller one with LP 2824 Plus

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I'm trying to resize automatic labels that comes from MercadoLibre.com.ar (latin american sell/buy page like eBay). They reccomend another zebra printer, but i have a smalller one, LP 2824 Plus.

The current code for every label looks like this

```
^XA

^FX MELI LOGO IMAGE
^FO50,50^GFA,6900,6900,50,,:::::::::::::::::::::::gI0FF,g01LF8,Y03IF00IFChO08,X03FEL07FChM07C,W01FCN03F8hL0FC,W0FCP03FhL0FC,V07ER07EhK0FC,U01FT0F8hJ0FC,U07CT03EhJ0FC,T01FV078hI0FC,T03CV03CO07F81FEI03FFJ07E01FF8003FF8007F8FC03FF8,T0FO0FN0FN01FFE3FF800IFC001FE07FFE00IFE00FFCFC0IFE,S01CM01IF8L038M03IF7FFC01IFE007FE0JF01JF03JFC1JF,S07CM07E07F8K01EM07LFE03JF00FFE1JF83JF83JFC3JF8,S0FF8K01EI03EK03FM07MF07FCFF81FFE3JFC3FC7F87JFC3FE7FC,R01C7FK078J0FCI01FB8L0FE1FF87F07F03FC1FFC7F81FC3F01F8FF07FC7F01FC,R0380FFI0FFK03FC01FE1CL0FC0FF03F8FE01FC3FC07F01FC3F01F8FE03FC7F00FE,R07001FF0FFEL07JF80EL0FC07E01F8FC00FC3F807E00FC3E01F8FC01FCFE00FE,R0EI01JF8M07FFI07K01F807E01F8FC00FC3F00FEM03FDFC01FCFE007E,Q01CJ01F87I0F8O038J01F807E01F8KFC3F00FEL0IF9FC00FCFC007F,Q018M0E003FEO018J01F807E01F9KFE3F00FEK07IF9FC00FCFC007F,Q03N0C00FDFP0CJ01F807E01F9KFE3F00FEJ01JF9FC00FCFC007F,Q07M01C01E03CO0EJ01F807E01F9KFE3F00FEJ03FFDF9FC00FCFC007F,Q06M03803801EO06J01F807E01F9FCI043F00FEJ07FC1F9FC00FCFC007F,Q0CM0700FI07O03J01F807E01F8FCJ03F00FEJ07F01F9FC00FCFC007F,Q0CM0601EI038N03J01F807E01F8FCJ03F00FE00FC7E01F9FC01FCFE007E,P018M07078I01CN018I01F807E01F8FCJ03F007F00FC7E01F8FC01FC7E00FE,P018M07FFK0FN018I01F807E01F8FE00FC3F007F01FC7E03F8FE03FC7F01FE,P018M01FCK078M018I01F807E01F87F03FC3F007F83FC7E07F8FF07F87F83FC,P03V03CN0CI01F807E01F87JF83F003JF87F9FF07JF83JFC,P03W0EN0CI01F807E01F83JF03F001JF07JF03JF01JF8,P038V07N0CI01F807E01F81IFE03F001IFE03IFE03IFE00JF,P03F8U038L07CI01F807E01F80IFC03FI07FFC01IFC00IFC007FFE,P03FF8T01CK03FCJ0F803E00F803FF003EI01FFI0FFEI03FFI01FF8,P031FFU0FJ03FEC,P0601FET038001FE04,P06001FCS01C00FE004,P06I03FT0E07FI0C,P07J07C78Q071F8I0EU01C1F81E,P07J01FFEFCL01803FCJ0CU07C3F83E,P03K07C7FEL01C01FK0CU07C3F83E,P03K038387M0E00EK0CU0FC3F87E,P038J030303FCK03006J01CU0FC3F87E,P038J03I03BEK03806J01CU0FC1F07E,P038J03K06K01C06J01CU0FCI07E,P03CJ038J07L0E0EJ03CU0FCI07E0FK0E007C,P01CJ01CCI03I030079CJ038U0FC1F87E3FCI07E03FF8,P01EK0FCI03I03803F8J078U0FC3F87F7FF001FE0IFE,P01EK03CI03E001C03EK078U0FC3F87JF807FE1JF,Q0FL0EI07FI0E038K0FV0FC3F87JFC0FFE3JF8,Q0F8K06J03800703K01FV0FC3F87JFC0FFE3JF8,Q07CK03F8001CC038FK03EV0FC3F87FC1FE1FFE7F01FC,Q07CK01F8I0C601FEK03EV0FC3F87F80FE1FC07E00FC,Q03EL07CI0C701FCK07CV0FC3F87F007E3F807E00FE,Q03FM0E300C381CL0FCV0FC3F87F007F3F80FE007E,Q01F8L07F00C1C38K03F8V0FC3F87F007F3F00KFE,R0FEL03F01C0FFL07FW0FC3F87E003F3F00KFE,R07FM0381E0FEL0FEW0FC3F87E003F3F00KFE,R07F8L01E7FFCL01FEW0FC3F87E003F3F00KFE,R03FEM07E3F8L07FCW0FC3F87E003F3F00FE,R01FFM018O0FF8W0FC3F87F007F3F00FC,S0FFCV03FFX0FC3F87F007F3F00FE,S07FFV0FFEX0FC3F83F007F3F007E,S01FFCT03FF8X0FC3F83F80FE3F007F00FC,T0IF8R01IFY0FC3F83FC1FE3F007F83FC,T07FFER07FFEY0FC3F81JFC3F003JFC,T01IFCP03IF8Y0FC3F81JFC3F001JF8,U07IFCN03IFEg0FC3F80JF83FI0JF,U03JFEL07JFCg0FC3F803FFE03FI07FFC,V07TFEgI01FI0FF801EJ0FF,V01TF8,W03RFC,X07PFE,Y0PF,g07LFE,gH03FFC,,:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::^FS

^FX MOTONORTE LOGO IMAGE
^FO250,835^GFA,3045,3045,35,,::::::::::::gL078gG03C,gL07CgG07E,gL07CgG07C,::R0E1F01FI01FC01FF001FC01C3FI03F003870FF801FE,07LFI01IFC7FC007FF03FFC07FF03IF800FFC07FF1FFC07FF8J01LFC,07LFI01LFE00IF83FFC0IF83IFC01FFE07FF1FFC0IFCJ01LFC,03KFEI01MF01IFC3FFC1IFC3IFE03IF87FF1FFC1IFEK0LF8,Q01MF83IFE1FF83IFE3JF07IF87FF1FFC3FCFF,Q01FC3FE1FC3F8FE0FC07F8FE3FC7F0FE1FC7F807E03F03F,Q01F81FC0FC7E03F07C07E07F3F03F0FC0FC7E007E03E01F8,Q01F81F80FC7E03F07C07E03F3F01F1F807E7E007E07E01F8,Q01F00F807C7C01F07C07C01F3F01F1F807E7C007E07JF8,Q01F00F807C7C01F87C0FC01F3F01F1F803E7C007E07JF8J08J01,03KFEI01F00F807C7C01F87C0FC01F3F01F1F003E7C007E07JF8J0LF8,:Q01F00F807C7C01F07C07C01F3F01F1F807E7C003E07E,Q01F00F807C7E01F07C07C03F3F01F1F807E7C003E07C,Q01F00F807C7E03F07E07E03F3F01F0FC0FC7C003E03E00F,Q01F00F807C3F07E07F07F07E3F01F0FE1FC7C003F03F03F,Q01F00F807C3IFE07FC3IFE3F01F07IF87C003FC3JF,Q01F00F807C1IFC03FC1IFC3F01F03IF87C003FE1IFE,07LFI01F00F807C0IF801FC0IF83F01F03FFE07C001FE0IFCJ01LFC,07LFI01F00F807C07FFI0FC07FF03F01F00FFC07CI0FC07FF8J01LFC,03KFEJ0F00F807C01FCI03801FC01E01F007F803CI01C01FEL0LF8,,::::::::g06V03T04J03001,g06L018N03T04J030018,g04L01O0301R08M018,J01E600E01E00C03804018078100EI0230303C06038I0701C03E0100F80E,J03FF01F03F01C03C0603C078100FI0230303C0E03CI0F01E07E0301F80F,J03FF03F03F83801E0607E0703807I073030380E01EI0E00E07303033807,J0I383F03381C07E0607E060381FI023030300C03EI0C03E0630303181F,J0I383E03180E07E0607C060383FI037030380C07EI0C07E0730303183F8,J0I383C03380E06E06070060383FI03F030180C06EI0C07E07F0303F83F8,J031100E03101C07C0603C060101FI03F0301C0807EI0C03E07E0301F01F,g0EV02V07,g0EgS06,g08gS02,,::::gN03030302102,gN040244031830018,gN040244031830108,gN0202C3031818108,gN018201008806008,gO0820080C806008,gN01820180C807008,,:::::::::::::^FS

^MMT
^PW799
^LL1519
^LS0
^FT256,928^XG000.GRF,1,1^FS
^FT32,192^XG001.GRF,1,1^FS
^FO14,13^GB772,1100,2^FS
^FO47,943^GB710,0,2^FS
^FO44,807^GB710,0,2^FS
^FO41,626^GB710,0,2^FS
^FO41,393^GB710,0,2^FS
^FO43,205^GB710,0,2^FS

^FT500,144^A0N,25,24^FH\^FDEmisi\A2n^FS
^FT578,144^A0N,25,24^FD03/02/2017 16:21^FS

^FT670,101^A0N,39,38^FDR2^FS
^FT670,249^A0N,39,38^FDC2^FS

^FT43,249^A0N,28,31^FDDestinatario:^FS
^FT45,280^A0N,25,24^FH\^FDBernardita Franco^FS
^FT510,280^A0N,21,20^FDTel: 0387156057943^FS
^FT45,310^A0N,25,24^FH\^FDAvenida Libertador 1154^FS
^FT45,340^A0N,25,24^FH\^FDpiso 14 A^FS
^FT45,370^A0N,25,24^FH\^FD(1112) autonoma - Capital Federal^FS


^FT41,443^A0N,28,31^FH\^FDNro. de Gu\A1a:^FS
^BY4,3,115^FT120,578^BCN,,Y,N
^FD0191070591^FS

^FT43,670^A0N,28,31^FDRemitente^FS
^FT45,698^A0N,25,24^FH\^FDIMPORTADORA FOTOGRAFICA SOCIEDAD ANONIMA^FS
^FT490,698^A0N,21,20^FDTel: (11)4643-2003 ^FS
^FT45,726^A0N,25,24^FH\^FDAv. Rivadavia 10820^FS
^FT45,752^A0N,25,24^FH\^FDImportadora Fotogr\A0fica S.A.^FS
^FT45,780^A0N,25,24^FH\^FD(1408) Liniers - Capital Federal^FS

^FT47,982^A0N,20,19^FH\^FDImportante: Se deja expresamente^FS
^FT319,982^A0N,20,19^FDaclarado que MercadoLibre^FS
^FT538,982^A0N,20,19^FH\^FDs\A2lo se limita a la^FS
^FT47,1010^A0N,20,19^FH\^FDpublicaci\A2n de anuncios^FS
^FT241,1010^A0N,20,19^FDde sus usuarios^FS
^FT370,1010^A0N,20,19^FDy no es el propietario,^FS
^FT545,1010^A0N,20,19^FDno ha vendido y no^FS
^FT47,1038^A0N,20,19^FH\^FDser\A0 responsable^FS
^FT182,1038^A0N,20,19^FH\^FDpor los art\A1culos^FS
^FT317,1038^A0N,20,19^FDentregados y/o contenidos^FS
^FT526,1038^A0N,20,19^FDen este paquete, ya que^FS
^FT47,1065^A0N,20,19^FDel vendedor es la persona^FS
^FT253,1065^A0N,20,19^FDidentificada en esta etiqueta.^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y

^XZ
```

What parameters should i change to make it work in a label such as: 2.5x4 inches?

Comment: Provide only small snippet that reproduces the problem, not the whole output. And give proper task description.

Answer (score 0):

This printers came by default in CPCL, you need to send the following command to change it to ZPL

```
! U1 setvar "device.languages" "zpl"
```

Comment: Hi! Im pretty an amateur with this. I certainly dont understand what's the point of changing the language.